# Variable containing multiple ECHO statements (via %nl% variable) doesn't expand correctly

Tags: variables, batch-file

Okay I have a variable that sets the statement `%nl%` to create a multiline
statement, inside that multiline statement is the variable `%resultA%`
and I want the whole statement (with the variable inside of it) to be inside another variable.

for example~
I want

```
set nl=^& echo.

echo ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»%nl%º  Player (Caesar)      º%nl%º         ^|              º%nl%º  Health ^| ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»   º%nl%º         ^| º%resultA%º   º%nl%º         ^| ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼   º%nl%ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼%nl%
```

to look like

```
set nl=^& echo.

set MyVar="echo ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»%nl%º  Player (Caesar)      º%nl%º         ^|             º%nl%º  Health ^| ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»   º%nl%º         ^| º%resultA%º   º%nl%º         ^| ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼   º%nl%ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼%nl%"
```

Whenever I call back the variable in the batch file I get an error
stating that `ECHO IS OFF`, of course I already know this but I'm trying to substitute multiple lines as one variable (with another variable inside of it) while echo is off...

Tried searching everywhere to no avail. Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Everything immediately after `=` in `set var=` goes into the variable including `"`.

Instead move the opening quote before the variable:

```
set "MyVar=echo ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»%nl%º ...................."
%MyVar%
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `set nl=^&echo.` does't create a new line character, instead it will split your echo into multiple parts and echo each part independently, but it's not very stable at all.

Better use a really new line character

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set nl=^
%=DONT_CHANGE_THIS_LINE=%
)
echo ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»!NL!º  Player (Caesar)      º!nl!º         ^|             º!nl!º  Health ^| ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»   º!nl!º         ^| º%resultA%º   º!nl!º         ^| ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼   º!nl!ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼!nl!
```

This newline character can only be used with delayed expansion!